# Is there a way to optionally import a package?

Tags: packages, conditionals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional “if a package is available”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/conditional-if-a-package-is-available)

I'm pretty lazy, and have my own `.sty` files which import a bunch of commonly used features. But, sometime system installations fail to provide one, for example Ubuntu's LaTeX doesn't have the `mathtext` package. So, is there a way to have a `\usepackage` command that won't cause (Xe)LaTeX to fail if a package isn't found?

Comment: I am not too sure if I understand the logic. If the file does not exist (you can use ifFileExists to check) you can stop the error for the package, but how about the commands that you are using from the package in the first place?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides for a package like `mathastext` it makes sense, since the document will compile without it…

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I'm using something like this in my package manuals to load font packages only if installed. After all, a manual in the standard font is much better than no manual :-)

Comment: @MartinScharrer In a package or class it makes sense, but in a preamble you should only load what you are going to use, otherwise it ends up like a collection of antiques:)

Comment: @Seamus ... you should try using `manuscript` sometimes as an alternative:)

Comment: This is actually a direct duplicate of [Only \usepackage if the package can be found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15862/only-usepackage-if-the-package-can-be-found), which itself got closed as a duplicate of [Conditional “if a package is available”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15306/conditional-if-a-package-is-available).