# How to warn if a package hasn't been loaded

Tags: packages, conditionals, warnings

Is it possible to emit a warning if a package hasn't been loaded?

If possible, I would prefer that the solution not require `\usepackage{ifthen}` as it couldn't emit the warning that it was missing the `ifthen` package.

EDIT: Thanks Martin and Joseph for the responses. I would like to clarify my question: *is it possible do to this from within the body of a document?*

The `\AtBeginDocument`, `\RequirePackage` and `\@ifpackageloaded` are only available in the preamble. The `ltxcmds` package makes `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` available in the body but then the `ltxcmds` package is required for this to work.

The situation where I would like this is I am generating tables with the `xtable` package in `R` and when the `floating.environment='sidewaystable'` argument is used, the `rotating` package is required. To make this easy for users, I would like to allow them to simply `\input{<path_to_xtable>}`. However, if the `rotating` package isn't loaded pdflatex give an error message like

```
l.3 \begin{sidewaystable}
                         [ht]
?
```

I would prefer that it issue a more informative warning that the `rotating` package is missing. Is this possible?

Comment: Related: [Test if a package is loaded](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16199) and [Is there any way to generate custom errors/warnings in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3306) (in combination). If you want to test if a package is installed see [Conditional "if a package is available"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15306).

Comment: these are helpful references, also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35282/how-to-implement-a-command-that-checks-for-loaded-packages

Comment: @momeara I've updated my answer, but I still don't see why you don't simply require the support package you need.

Comment: Do you mean by using \RequirePackage? Or some other method?

Answer (score 11):

Most of the time you don't test in this way but simply require those packages you need, but of course there are cases where load-order is awkward and a test is useful. The standard way to do this would be to test at the start of the document

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{OtherPackage}% Fill in name here
    {}% Nothing to say
    {%
      \PackageWarning{MyPackage}
         {You have not loaded the 'OtherPackage' package!}%
    }%
}
```

---

To allow a check in the document body, the usual way is to define a conditional

```
\newif\ifmy@check@OtherPackage@loaded
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{OtherPackage}% Fill in name here
    {\my@check@OtherPackage@loadedtrue}% Nothing to say
    {\my@check@OtherPackage@loadedfalse}%
}
```

and then to use that conditional to check for the package being available.